Material is getting messed up after "Cell Fracture"
I have simple building structure with some material. "Cell Fracture" is messing up the material / paint on the building
Is this a single material? --> 4 material slots
How is it applied? --> By assigning material slots to different faces of cube (Principle BSDF)
Does it usetextures? --> Not to my knowledge, simply used "Assign" to the faces of cube
Are they parametric or image based? --> No idea used Priciple BSDF based system
How is the node tree of the materials? --> I don't know
What texture coordinates are they using? --> No idea
I had a similar construct in separate project but "Cell Fracture" worked for it, I messed it up for other reasons and was just restarting with this and got stuck with "Cell Fracture" messing the materials. Am at early learning stage, probably missing something basic / silly.
.




Pretty sure that isn't supposed to happen. You should probably file a bug report.

You seem to be having issues with materials, but you did not show us anything about your materials. Is this a single material? How is it applied? Does it usetextures? Are they parametric or image based? How is the node tree of the materials? What texture coordinates are they using? Cell fracture is most likely altering the UVs of your objects. Please edit your post and provide all pieces of the puzzle so we can diagnose the issue without having to blindly guess around.

Thanks  @DuarteFarrajotaRamos have updated question with more details, I did not know need to be provided

Cell Fracture seems to be altering your material assignments. Haven't used it in quite a while. See if there is an option to preserve original material slots, otherwise you may have to either separate your wall colors into separate objects, or separate chunks of wall by color, or find some other way to define color assignments, like with a texture or masks
